# Why does my django web app on shared hosting have its GET urls treated differently than POST urls

Tags: python, django, apache, passenger

I have a django web app on **A2hosting**, where I am using **.htaccess** files and **passenger_wsgi.py**. It was working fine the last time I touched it, but then someone who had a look at it later informed me that it was broken.

I created a test situation to find the problem and here's the gist of it.

When I do a **GET** (to `www.geo4ce.com/quiz/test_weird/`), it goes to a page with a simple form that just has one input and a submit and an action that has "`/quiz/test_weird/`" and `method="post"`.  When I submit the form, the server expects the "quiz" part of the url to be referring to a path on the file server, can't find it and then logs an error that it can't find it.  But, then it checks the test_weird part of the url against my django **urls.py** file, finds a different view for that and displays it.

A scenario that almost works properly is with `www.geo4ce.com/quiz/test_hacked/`, that has the same set up, except the form has action = "`/anythinghere/quiz/test_hacked/`".  In this case, the "anythinghere" part of the url gets an error logged, since it doesn't exist on the file server, and then the `/quiz/test_hacked/` part of the url works normally to get back to the original web page.

Anyone have any idea how I might be able to fix or debug this?

**[EDIT]**
I don't think it's the .htaccess file that's the cause.  It looks something like this.

```
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerAppRoot /path/to/app/folder/

# Prevent Apache from serving .htaccess files:
<FilesMatch "^\.htaccess">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


deny from xxx.yyy.zzz
```

Comment: Does your .htaccess manipulate the requests? Please show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is caused by a certain version of Passenger (with RoR).  I've been told to switch to using FCGI.